# contribution to the average

Tags: arithmetic

I'm calculating the conversion rate by employee.

Employee1 got 2 new customers out of 8 that he was working with.

Employee2 got 3 out of 6.

Employee3 got 0 out of 2.

- Conversion rate of Employee1 is 2/8 =  0.25
- Conversion rate of Employee2 is 3/6 =  0.5
- Conversion rate of Employee3 is 0/2 =  0
- Conversion rate total is 5/16 = 0.3125

I'm trying to figure out how much of the total was due to Employee1, 2 and 3?

Comment: Well, the total is 5 so I guess Employee1 had 2 of the 5 and Employee2 had 3 of the 5 new customers. Do you agree?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Employee $\#1$ got $2$ out of the $5$, as you tell us.  What else are you asking?   Just knowing the individual rates, without the underlying numbers, would have made it hard to say much.

Comment: I think the individual hit rate of an employee tells you more about the employee than the second measure you propose. Say for ex: $E_1$ gets $1$ out of $100$ people he talks to and $E_2$ gets $1$ out of $2$ people he talks to. From the second measure both these employees are equally good because their contribution is $50\%$ each to the total but that is clearly not the case.

Comment: @Vizag I am no specialist of this matter, but I would not say "that is clearly not the case". It may depend on so many factors. For instance, one big client may count more in the revenue that $100$ small ones. Here there are many hidden hypotheses on what makes a "good" employee. It's more a question of strategic decision-making than mathematics. I don't expect that a single indicator will allow a faithful comparison.

Comment: Yes Jean true you're right. I made an implicit assumption of these clients being of somewhat comparable sizes. But yes, my bad.

Comment: THe company conversion rate was 0.3125. This number is calculate out of the total.

However, I want to find a percentage of each employee.

How much, did Employee 1, 2 and 3 contributed to the total of 0.3125?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$0.3125\cdot {2\over 5}=0.125\\0.3125\cdot {3\over 5}=0.1875\\0.3125\cdot {0\over 5}=0\phantom{0000}$$

It really is that simple. Until you take other factors into consideration, like the comments did.